# "Send Notification Email" option behavious depending upon change in Case ownership (for a particular record type only)

Tags: case

For a particular Case Record Type, I would like to

- "Send Notification Email" option should automatically get checked when the ownership is being changed to USER
- "Send Notification Email" option should automatically get unchecked when the owenership is being changed to QUEUE

However, I want it only for a one Record Type and not for all the record types in cases.

I shall appreciate for solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have direct access to the ownership change page so there's no direct way of doing this. I can think of two option and both these options will work only if the sidebar is enabled in your org:

1) Create a custom VF page which will mimic the standard change owner page. As this is a custom page you will have full control to check / uncheck the checkbox based on your condition. Create a home page sidebar component which will contain a script (jQuery / javascript) which will override the [change Owner] link to you VF page. So whenever a user click on the [change owner] link, he will be redirected to your VF page.

2) Now, If you do not want to create a VF page then create a home page component which will contain a script, this script will run only when you click on the change owner link, the script will check if the case record record type and the owner that is being changed to and based on this it will check / uncheck the "send email notification" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with workflow rules:
Create a rule that checks if the owner of a case is changed, if the owner is a queue and if the record type is the one you want. If yes, send an email alert to the new owner. This way, no one has to use the "Send Notification Email" checkbox.